# Why does Sharepoint delta query not return all elements on initial request?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to keep a synced list of files in a Sharepoint group by calling:

```
/groups/{groupId}/drive/root/delta
```

When there is no token submitted in the request, it should return the current state, but some files are missing. I'm looping all pages by following odata.nextlink, but I only get 3102 elements, compared to 3134 elements in Sharepoint (exported to Excel). There seems to be no logic in the files missing

Comment: [Darrel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6819/darrel-miller) or [Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105518/marc-lafleur), do you have any insights on this?

Comment: Can you provide a request-id (included in the response headers) and a time stamp for the call that returns the last page?  The Delta API should generally not be missing anything.  What method are you using to count the elements in SharePoint?

Comment: Hi Jeremy. Sorry for taking this long to get back, but I had to do other tasks. I've synced again with this request id: 3068cfaf-de71-4099-82bf-abcbb0190832 and time : Tue, 12 Mar 2019 14:40:57 GMT. This results in 2324 files from that sharepoint group. I then export the list from sharepoint ui, with "Export to Excel", and filter on "elements", and there are 2644 files. If I compare the lists, it's completely random files that are missing from the sync. The OneDrive client syncs the files just fine.

Comment: Hi [Jeremy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10281080/jeremy-kelley-microsoft). Did you have a look at this?